# SQL SELECT Sum values without including duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, sum

I have a problem in Oracle SQL that I'm trying to get my head around.

I'll illustrate with an example. I have three tables that I am querying:

```
Employees
__________________________________________
| EmployeeID | Name                      |
| 1          | John Smith                |
| 2          | Douglas Hoppalot          |
| 3          | Harry Holiday             |
... 



InternalCosts
________________________________
| IntID | Amount | EmployeeID  |
| 1     | 10     |     1       |
| 2     | 20     |     2       |
| 3     | 30     |     1       |
...


ExternalCosts
________________________________
| ExtID | Amount | EmployeeID  |
| 1     | 40     |     1       |
| 2     | 50     |     2       |
| 3     | 60     |     1       |
...
```

What I want to achieve is a result of one row per employee, with sums of each of their internal and external costs, i.e.

```
____________________________________________________________
| Name             | InternalCostTotal | ExternalCostTotal |
| John Smith       | 40                | 100               |
| Douglas Hoppalot | 20                | 50                |
...
```

The problem I have is that when I query both the InternalCosts and ExternalCosts tables, I get each permutation of costs, not just one per employee. When I group by employee Name and sum the amount fields the values are too high. What I have tried:

```
SELECT emp.Name, sum(int.Amount), sum(ext.Amount) 
FROM Employees emp,
     InternalCosts int,
     ExternalCosts ext
WHERE emp.EmployeeId = int.EmployeeID
  and emp.EmployeeID = ext.EmployeeID
GROUP BY emp.Name
```

The examples above would return:

```
 ____________________________________________________________
 | Name             | InternalCostTotal | ExternalCostTotal |
 | John Smith       | 80                | 200               | <- too high!
 | Douglas Hoppalot | 20                | 50                |
 ...
```

Grateful for any help/advice/thoughts!

Comment: the problem is when you are connecting employees with internalcosts you get two rows when employeeid =1 and when you join the resultant 2 rows with externalcosts it will return 4 rows and then calculating the sum. Put int.extid=int.intid in where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use subqueries on int and ext to do the summing, and join to the subqueries.

I also suggest using explicit JOINs rather than table, table, table

e.g.

```
SELECT emp.Name, int.Amount AS InternalCostTotal, ext.Amount AS ExternalCostTotal
FROM Employees emp
JOIN ( 
    SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount 
    FROM InternalCosts 
    GROUP BY EmployeeID 
) int ON emp.EmployeeId = int.EmployeeID
JOIN ( 
    SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount 
    FROM ExternalCosts 
    GROUP BY EmployeeID 
) ext ON emp.EmployeeId = ext.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/827e9/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( EmployeeID, Name ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'John Smith' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Douglas Hoppalot' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Harry Holiday' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE InternalCosts ( IntID, Amount, EmployeeID ) AS
          SELECT 1, 10, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 20, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 30, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE ExternalCosts ( ExtID, Amount, EmployeeID ) AS
          SELECT 1, 40, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 50, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 60, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT e.*,
       ( SELECT SUM( Amount ) FROM InternalCosts i WHERE e.EmployeeID = i.EmployeeID ) AS InternalCostTotal,
       ( SELECT SUM( Amount ) FROM ExternalCosts x WHERE e.EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID ) AS ExternalCostTotal
FROM   Employees e
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/827e9/1/0)**:

```
| EMPLOYEEID |             NAME | INTERNALCOSTTOTAL | EXTERNALCOSTTOTAL |
|------------|------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|          1 |       John Smith |                40 |               100 |
|          2 | Douglas Hoppalot |                20 |                50 |
|          3 |    Harry Holiday |            (null) |            (null) |
```

Or (using joins):

```
WITH InternalTotals AS (
  SELECT EmployeeID,
         SUM( Amount ) AS InternalCostTotal
  FROM   InternalCosts
  GROUP BY
         EmployeeID
),
ExternalTotals AS (
  SELECT EmployeeID,
         SUM( Amount ) AS ExternalCostTotal
  FROM   ExternalCosts
  GROUP BY
         EmployeeID
)
SELECT e.EmployeeID,
       i.InternalCostTotal,
       x.ExternalCostTotal
FROM   Employees e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       InternalTotals i
       ON ( e.EmployeeID = i.EmployeeID )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ExternalTotals x
       ON ( e.EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT emp.Name, NVL(IntAmount,0), NVL(ExtAmount,0)
FROM Employees emp
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT EmployeeID, sum(Amount) as IntAmount
     FROM InternalCosts GROUP BY EmployeeID) int
    ON emp.EmployeeID = int.EmployeeID
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT EmployeeID, sum(Amount) as ExtAmount
     FROM ExternalCosts GROUP BY EmployeeID) ext
    ON emp.EmployeeID = ext.EmployeeID
```

Please also note that normalizing your table structure could help you in this case and in the future probably (and by this I mean merging External and Internal costs into one table, provided that it is possible of course).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the query I'm working on is a lot more complex than in my example, and is dynamically constructed within a PowerBuilder application, so working with joins is not something I want to get into in this case. Normally I always try to use joins though, I prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try a group by using **Employee ID** instead and later do an INNER join to project the names from the **Employee** table.

Cheers!

Comment: How about adding the query about as per your suggestion to support your answer? It will give a more clear picture of what you are trying to say.

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution from one of the other answers, but I really appreciate you answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.emp_name,inernalAmount,sum(ext.Amount) as externalAmount from
(
SELECT emp.EmployeeID,emp.Name, sum(int.Amount) as internalAmount 
FROM Employees emp inner join InternalCosts int on emp.EmployeeId = int.EmployeeID
) t1 inner join ExternalCosts ext on t1.EmployeeID = ext.EmployeeID
GROUP BY t1.Name,internalAmount
```

Comment: Your query doesn't work, as is. You're missing a group by from your subquery, plus t1.emp_name doesn't exist (t1.name?) and you've misspelt "internalamount" in your outer select's column list.

Comment: Thanks, I got a solution for my problem for one of the other problems, but it was really nice of you to answer my question.